# Reading null value for label in application

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my application reading value from front end into label lbBillableAmount1 but somehow null value is passed to it and code block terminates and transfers to catch block.Please refer below code:

```
 protected void RPClientWish_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if(Convert.ToInt32(Session["RoleId"])==1)
            {
                Label lb2 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lb2");
                lb2.Visible = true;
                Label lbBillableAmount1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label7");

                lbBillableAmount1.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Please let me know solution for this because even after dropping label and creating new one still getting error.
    Error is :Object reference not set to an instance of object.
     I have read lot of posts for this error but nothing is solving the issue.

Here is my repeater code:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="RPClientWish" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="RPClientWish_ItemDataBound" >
       <HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="col-md-12">
     <div class="EmployeeList">
             <div class="col-md-3">
     <asp:Label ID="lbname" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Name" style="font-family:'Segoe UI';"></asp:Label>
           </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"> &nbsp;</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-2"><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Hours" style="font-family:'Segoe UI';"></asp:Label></div>
      <div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
                                                                <div class="col-md-2"><asp:Label ID="lb1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Billable Hours" style="font-family:'Segoe UI';"></asp:Label></div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
      <asp:Label ID="lb2" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Billable Amount" style="font-family:'Segoe UI';" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                   </div>
         </div>
      </div>
           </HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="col-md-12">
             <div class="EmployeeList">
            <div class="col-md-3">
<asp:Label ID="lbClientname" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%# Eval("ClientName")%>' style="font-family:'Segoe UI';"></asp:Label>
                                                                </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"> &nbsp;</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="col-md-2"><asp:Label ID="lbhours" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text='<%# Eval("TotalHours")%>' style="font-family:'Segoe UI';"></asp:Label></div>
 <div class="col-md-1">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-md-2"><asp:Label ID="lbBillableHours1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="00" style="font-family:'Segoe UI';" ></asp:Label></div>
      <div class="col-md-2">

**<asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </div>**
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12"><hr /></div>
   </div>

 </ItemTemplate>

  </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: How are you assigning `label17` in aspx designer view?

Comment: show aspx markup  for `lbBillableAmount1`

Comment: @user3714403 There is no label with name `lbBillableAmount1` in your aspx markup so thats the reason you are getting nullreference

Comment: @Webruster I've accidentally rejected your edit request, as the side-by-side comparison did not show the entire code-snippet, and it appeared to have a bunch of code not added by the OP. If the entire edit is rejected, please make the edit again and ping me so I can approve it. Cheers.

Comment: @Webruster - He is finding `Label7` and not `lbBillableAmount1`

Comment: @Rohit he modified the question but didnt informed here thank you!! (you can see in the revision)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `label7` is defined in `ItemTemplate` so you have to search that label only in `ListItemType` as `Item`. For first time when event got fired it has `HeaderTemplate` so it doesn't find any `Lable` with id  `lable7` that causes error.So here is the code to access `lable7`

```
    protected void RPClientWish_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if(Convert.ToInt32(Session["RoleId"])==1)
                {
                 if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header)
                   {
                    Label lb2 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lb2");
                    lb2.Visible = true;
                   }
                 else if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                   {
                    Label lbBillableAmount1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label7");

                    lbBillableAmount1.Visible = true;
                  }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Used above code block but now getting null exception at lb2

Comment: `lb2` is in `HeaderTemplate`  for that it is showing error. let me update my code.

Comment: This code is working but in repeater control it is displaying data for first row only and not for other rows.While debugging it jumps to other code block instead of going in else if block.

Comment: first row means only for HeaderTemplate ? Is there any error?

Comment: Not for header template,this is properly visible.It is displaying data in item template but only value for first row and not after that

Comment: also add  `e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem` in else if section `else if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem )`